# Solving Systems of Equations While Graphing

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

State the conditions for which the system below is:

1. consistent and independent
2. consistent and dependent
3. inconsistent.

$$
\begin{cases}
ax+by=c\\
dx+ey=f
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.
Also, as @Moo, already told, you're more likely to be well received if you show us your efforts and attempts, instead of merely stating your question.

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I am new to the site. I have not tried anything as I do not know really what the question is asking nor where to start so I was hoping maybe someone could guide me. I guess I could plug in random numbers but is that what this is asking? And is there a better way?

Comment: I have not learned Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: I talked to a professor of mine and figured it out. Thank you for your help!